# In Azure DevOps is it possible to use the Associated Automation tab in a test case to track tests created outside the Microsoft ecosystem?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, katalon-studio, testcomplete

From all documentation I've found online there doesn't seem to be a way to manually mark that a test has associated automation with it.  I've only seen documentation on how to associate tests created within Visual Studio with Azure DevOps.

Does anyone know a solution that works with third party applications like TestCafe, TestComplete, Katalon Studio, etc?  It's hard to know to how complete our automation coverage is without being able to update these fields.

We are currently using Katalon Studio as our automation solution. We have integrated it as best we can with Azure DevOps, but it appears to only work one way (Katalon sending test results to DevOps). It is not recognizing that there are automated tests associated with these test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps only supports associating test cases with the test in Visual Studio currently. If you want to track your auto test using test case, it's recommended to use VS.